# python network file writing in a robust manner

Tags: python, file, networking

I am looking for a robust way to write out to a network drive.  I am stuck with WinXP writing to a share on a Win2003 server.  I want to pause writing if the network share goes down... then reconnect and continue writing once the network resource is available.  With my initial code below, what happens is the 'except' catches the IOError when the drive goes away, but then when the drive becomes available again, the outf operations continue to IOError.

```
import serial

with serial.Serial('COM8',9600,timeout=5) as port, open('m:\\file.txt','ab') as outf:
    while True:
        x = port.readline() # read one line from serial port
        if x:   # if the there was some data
            print x[0:-1]     # display the line without extra CR
            try:
                outf.write(x) # write the line to the output file
                outf.flush() # actually write the file
            except IOError: # catch an io error
                print 'there was an io error'
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that once an open file goes into an error state because of the IOError that you will need to reopen it.  You could try something like this:

```
with serial.Serial('COM8',9600,timeout=5) as port:
    while True:
        try:
            with open('m:\\file.txt','ab') as outf:
                while True:
                    x = port.readline() # read one line from serial port
                    if x:   # if the there was some data
                        print x[0:-1]     # display the line without extra CR
                        try:
                            outf.write(x) # write the line to the output file
                            outf.flush() # actually write the file
                break
        except IOError:
            print 'there was an io error'
```

This puts the exception handling inside an outer loop that will reopen the file (and continue reading from the port) in the event of an exception.  In practice you would probably want to add a `time.sleep()` or something to the `except` block in order to prevent the code from spinning.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct - the IO error in this case practically means "this file handle is invalid" (because the underlying resource is unavailable). Once it is invalid it won't become valid again, so you **have** to reopen the file to create a new valid file handle. This isn't python-specific but true for any programming language, because the file handles are governed (and thus invalidated) by the OS kernel.

Comment: Thanks larsks.  I just had to move your 'break' statement over by 3 tab stops.  Then I added one iteration of a 'spinning wheel' text animation inside the IOError which has the sleep as well.  The code works perfectly.  I can pull out the ethernet cable, and it gracefully reconnects and continues writing once the cable is reconnected.  Thank you for your help!